I am recieving the error 77 when using ./configure in the chroot from LFS
I am trying to compile GetText in the chroot from LFS step 7.7 and when i run ./configure it exits and says
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local' '--disable-shared' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/sources/gettext-0.22.4/gettext-runtime':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
configure: error: ./configure failed for gettext-runtime

And then when i check the config.log it tells me that the error code is "configure: exit 77", this also happens when i try to run ./configure on any other of them, such as bison. How do i fix this, I am on Ubuntu 24.04

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

@David I am using Ubuntu 24.04
